# Comment and reply system

Tags: php, json

I am trying to make a comment and reply system but I'm facing some issues. I want to print comments and replies in JSON, like this:

```
{"comment":"data1","reply":[{"comment_id":"15","comment":"reply1"}]}
```

I have done this, but replies repeat in comments that do not have this reply:

```
{"comment":"data1","reply":[{"comment_id":"15","comment":"reply1"}]}

{"comment":"data2","reply":[{"comment_id":"15","comment":"reply1"},{"comment_id":"14","comment":"reply2"}]}

{"comment":"Легко. data3 ","reply":[{"comment_id":"15","comment":"reply1"},{"comment_id":"14","comment":"reply2"},{"comment_id":"13","comment":"reply3"},{"comment_id":"13","comment":"reply4"}]}
```

For example in the second comment in replies it show the reply from the first comment, but it but it shouldn't show.

```
<?
$sql = "select * from comments where post_id=:post_id order by id desc";
$data = $db->prepare($sql);
$data->execute(array(':post_id' => $post_id));
$comments = $data->fetchAll();
$count = $data->rowCount();

foreach ($comments as $com) {
    $sql = "select * from reply where post_id=? and comment_id=? order by id desc";
    $data = $db->prepare($sql);
    $data->execute([$com['post_id'], $com['id']]);
    $replies = $data->fetchAll();

    foreach ($replies as $reply) {
        $xxx[] = [
            'comment_id' => $reply['comment_id'],
            'comment' => $reply['comment'],
        ];
        $xyc = [
            'comment' => $com['comment'],
            'reply' => $xxx,
        ];
    }
    echo json_encode($xyc, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    echo "<br></br>";

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset `$xxx` every time you process a new comment. Otherwise you just keep on adding to it, which is why later output also contains replies from earlier comments.

```
foreach ($comments as $com) {
  $xxx = array();
  //... etc
```

Also, to make the code more efficient you only need to run

```
$xyc = [
   'comment' => $com['comment'],
    'reply' => $xxx,
];
```

once, after the inner foreach loop has ended. Right now it runs once for every reply, which is unnecessary - you want to wait till all the replies have been processed, and then create the final object.

So:

```
foreach ($replies as $reply) {
    $xxx[] = [
        'comment_id' => $reply['comment_id'],
        'comment' => $reply['comment'],
    ];
}

$xyc = [
    'comment' => $com['comment'],
    'reply' => $xxx,
];

echo json_encode($xyc, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
echo "<br></br>";
```

would make more sense for that section of the code.

Comment: I may have done something wrong, but nothing has changed

Comment: Maybe you did. I simulated this as best I can without access to your database, and it seems to work: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8d36a99b7e3adee94754b5ce5dfd5d6ba5ca054f . So either you've made some kind of mistake, or it's also possible that the data coming out of the database isn't what you expected.

Comment: i understood, your code prints just last reply, one. But in one comment i have more than one reply, so because of that your code is working. Look at. my last comment, there have to be 2 replies. Can you help me to do this with multiple replies, i will be very thankful to you

Comment: No change to the code is required when there are multiple replies. New demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4c19e7b44df492fa08bbdf83e4766f1768620252